# Send subdomain as post data

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

Having spent the past few hours looking for a solution, I thought I'd ask here.

I'm looking for a way to process links such as:

> http://subdomain.domain.com/page/subpage/

so they are passed to the server as:

> http://domain.com/index.php?subdomain=subdomain&page=page&subpage=subpage

which can be taken by index.php to display the correct page information.

I can get the page and subpage to work but have no clue how to get the subdomain. Note: if there is no subdomain, I would like that field to either be left blank or contain a default value.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. :)

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, I want the first URL to be what the user sees and can input into the address bar and the second URL to be the page that is loaded by the server when the user navigates to the first URL.

My .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove 'www'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Add slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://resolutiongaming.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Subdomain redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^resolutiongaming.com$
RewriteRule ^webdev/$ http://webdev.resolutiongaming.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^artwork/$ http://artwork.resolutiongaming.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^music/$ http://music.resolutiongaming.com [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Comment: Send data via GET method

Comment: I think you are looking for mod_rewrite, checkout http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this in one .htacces file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*     http://domain.com/index.php?subdomain=%1&page=%2&subpage=%3  [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect permanently:

`http://subdomain.domain.com/page/subpage/` or `http://www.subdomain.domain.com/page/subpage/`

To:

`http://domain.com/index.php?subdomain=subdomain&page=page&subpage=subpage`

For the rule to work, the incoming URL scheme: `/page/subpage/` must be kept.

To replace permanent redirection with silent mapping, remove `R=301` from [R=301,L] or replace it with `R` for temporal redirection.

Comment: This seemed quite promising but doesn't work for some reason. I think it may be something to do with the webhost (000webhost) not recognizing the subdomain. I have updated my original question with my htaccess file but I'll accept this answer as it seems to be exactly what I wanted.